# Django running in Docker container: makemigrations and migrate do not see app's model on launch

Tags: django, docker, migrate, makemigrations

I have Django running in a Docker container. The CMD of my Docker file simply runs a script, launch.sh, which *inter alia* has the following commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --no-input --verbosity 1
python manage.py migrate --no-input --verbosity 1
```

So, these commands make migrations on my Django project, and then perform the migrations (if any), whenever my container launches. This works as intended for the specifically *project-level* migrations.

However, inevitably, *only* the project-level migrations are made — that is, the *app-level* migrations are never made and so are never performed. *But* if I log into the container (with docker exec -it ... bash) and execute the same migration commands manually, the app-level migrations *are* made and performed.

Googling and numerous variations to my code haven't turned up any explanations for this behavior or any fix, so I'm stumped.

Any ideas?

P.S. Here is my project and app structure:

```
/django/
    project/
    app/
    static/
    manage.py
```

Also, I tried executing the same set of commands twice in succession in my script, and also running the same set of commands in succession but with my app specified as the target option, but these attempts still produced the same results: only the project migrations are made, not the app migrations.

As asked, here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1 
ADD django-requirements.pip . 
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \ 
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r django-requirements.pip 
WORKDIR / 
ADD launch.sh . 
CMD ./launch.sh
```

My Django project is mounted at launch at /django, and my launch script CDs to /django before running the migration commands.

Comment: I should state that I'm using Django 2.0, Python 3, and the latest version of Docker.

Comment: One other piece of _possibly_ relevant information: my Django project isn't "in" the Docker container. Rather it lives in the local filesystem and is mounted into the container via Docker run option on launch.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Django app Dokerfile for `WORKDIR`

```
# In my case it is /app
WORKDIR /app
```

and change your  *launch.sh* file

```
# manage.py will be inside working dir 
python /app/manage.py migrate --noinput
```

**UPDATE**

> It depends on where you copied *`launch.sh`* file inside the
>   container.

If you copied all files of Django app inside `/app` dir

```
COPY . /app
```

and copy your *launch.sh* file outside it like

```
COPY ./<path to launch file>/launch.sh /launch.sh
```

then inside *launch.sh* you have to use *manage.py* as

```
# should prepend `/app/` 
python /app/manage.py migrate --noinput
```

But if you copied launch.sh inside `/app/` as.

```
COPY ./<path to launch file>/launch.sh /app/launch.sh
```

Then you can use migrate command as the traditional way

```
python manage.py migrate --noinput
```

> Now When you run the command using **docker exec -it** `container-id`, Then it runs
>   inside working DIR and locates *manage.py* file.

Comment: Thanks! I can try that, but: 1) it doesn't explain why the same commands work when executed manually in the container from the same location; and 2) I shouldn't have to change the structure of my project to make this work, since it's pretty standard: my manage.py is in the same parent directory as my project and my app, and these commands are _supposed_ to find all migrations project-wide.

Comment: @CarlF.Hostetter check update section, hope this helps

Comment: Also can you post your DockerFile as well

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.
I think there must be a `migrations/__init__.py` in your Django app dir.
Be sure that you copied it to your container.
My solution was to change a line in .dockerignore:
`app/migrations/*` to `app/migrations/0*`.